# Tarantool shiny dashboard

Tags: charts, dashboard, tarantool, nosql

I want to use Tarantool database for logging user activity.
Are there any out of the box solutions to create web dashboard with nice charts based on the collected data?

Comment: read the guidelines for posting, stack does not recommend third party libraries

Answer (score 1):

Tarantool has embedded lua language so u could generate json from your data and use any charting library. For example [D3.js](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery) has method to load json directly from url.

> d3.json(url[, callback])
>
> Creates a request for the JSON file at the specified url with the mime type "application/json". If a callback is specified, the request is immediately issued with the GET method, and the callback will be invoked asynchronously when the file is loaded or the request fails; the callback is invoked with two arguments: the error, if any, and the parsed JSON. The parsed JSON is undefined if an error occurs. If no callback is specified, the returned request can be issued using xhr.get or similar, and handled using xhr.on.

You also could look at [c3.js](http://c3js.org/) simple facade for d3

Answer (score 1):

A long time ago, using an old-old version of tarantool I've created a draft of [tarbon](https://github.com/Mons/tarbon) - time-series database, with carbon-cache identical interface.
Since that time the protocol have changed, but the generic idea still the same: use spaces to store data, compact data organization and correct indexes to access spaces as time-series rows and lua for preparing resulting jsons.
That solution was perfect in performance (either on reads or on writes), but that old version lacks disk storage and without disk I was very limited to metrics capacity.